# Authentication Required error when sending email with Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, gmail

I'm trying to send a password-reset email using gmail server but I'am getting an error. 'SMTPSenderRefused Authentication Required'

The google account have - 1. 2-Step Verification on 2. Third-party access through app password 3. Access allowed for less secure app : On

'''
    setting.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'  
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER') #my gmail acc
EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD') #app password from gmail acc
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

'''

'''
urls.py

```
path('password-reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name='users/password-reset.html'), name='password_reset'),
path('password-reset-done/', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
    template_name='users/password-reset-done.html'), 
    name='password_reset_done'),
path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
    PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'),
    name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

'''

I expect an email with a reset-password-link send to the user or whomever POSTed their email when prompted but what i get is this error -

'''

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /password-reset/
(530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError p17sm3671371wrq.95 - 
gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

create a new account in google and avoid two step verification.
Add your account name and password to settings directly
It will work

As you are new, hardcore these details directly to settings.py later you can configure in local environment

Comment: Thank you Anoop, still have the same error even with the new email. The reason the details are not hard-coded is because the code is seen by public in here.

Comment: Add the below code to settings.py       
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your email id'        
SERVER_EMAIL = 'your email id'

Comment: To send test email from your Django application, open the shell command and enter below code 
                               from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)

Comment: getting this error : [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)

Comment: Can you try EMAIL_PORT = 465

Comment: Yes i did try PORT 465, but  get a different error : 'SMTPServerDisconnected, Connection unexpectedly closed'. I think the issue might be my machine, will have to try the same code with another machine...

Comment: hi, make gmail accessible to less secured apps, avoid two step verification, hardcore data directly to settings.py, follow the tutorial https://youtu.be/vESZbORzE-8